# Access 192.168.x.y from 10.x.y.z VM?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine

Situation is as follows: I have a Macbook Pro in a local network with a `192.168.x.y` address. On it runs a VM with Ubuntu 22.04 with a shared network which is `10.0.2.x`. The host (macOS) has an IP `10.0.2.2` from within the VM so I can tunnel SSH to another port number by:

```
ssh -N -L 9100:<printer IP>:9100 user@10.0.2.2 &
```

where `<printer IP>` is in the host's `192.168` IP range.

But that does not always work as sometimes port numbers used by the printer (or any device to be reached via the host) are also used by the host and other port numbers cannot be used.

Is there another way to reach `192.168.x.y` addresses from the Linux VM while retaining shared network or NAT in the VM?

Comment: Are you saying the different addresses already prevent communication? They aren't supposed to.

Answer (score 2):

The network connection between your VM and other machines on the host's local network is controlled by the VM software network configuration - you can probably put it into NAT mode, which will allow communication out. Sometimes you can put it into bridge mode, where the VM appears to be a machine on its own on the local network.